# How to control RC Servo motor using 8051?

Tags: c, 8051

I'm using an 8051 MCU and I wish to control an RC servo motor with 2 push buttons for an RC toy car.

I have code to use two buttons, one for right and another for left.

When I click one button, the servo motor moves in one direction but then remains at this position.

What I want is that when I push the button the servo motor should move in one direction and return to its initial position upon button release.

I tried this code, but it did not work for me.

```
#include<reg51.h>
sbit output=P1^0;  
sbit S1 = P2^0; 
sbit S2 = P2^1;       

void timer(int msec)     // Function for timer
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<msec;i++)
    {

        TMOD=0x20;         // Mode2
        TH1=0xFF;
        TL1=0xD1;
        //TH1= -23;        // 50usec timer
        TR1=1;
        while(TF1==0);
        TF1=0;
        TR1=0;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i;

    output=0;

    while(1)
    {
        //move to LEFT
        if (S1==0)
        for(i=0;i<300;i++)
        {
            output=1;
            timer(20);
            output=0;
            timer(40);

            output=1;
            timer(40);
            output=0;
            timer(40);

        }
        //move to RIGHT
        if (S2 == 0)
        for(i=0;i<300;i++)
        {
            output=1;
            timer(40);
            output=0;
            timer(40);

            output=1;
            timer(20);
            output=0;
            timer(40);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return back to initial position?, what initial position is in terms of configuration servo motor?,how many steps?,what position you mean in steps,which microcontroller are you using?,some need pull at port 1 when using as input,The system is doing what you return in the code.Output 0 means no supply,It doesnot alter the polarity driving the motor in opp. direction.

Comment: The code is in desperate need of commenting and indentation.

Comment: Initial is when the servo motor is in 0°, the servo motor is configured to 0° to 90°, the microccontroller used is 8051 as indicated in my question, i know the system is doing what the code returns, Output 0 means no supply, i don't want to alter the plolarity, it's a servo motor. The code is not complicated simple so i did not put any comments.

Comment: No when i hold the button the Servo motor moves to one position and did not return to its initial position.

Comment: a servo motor requires a PWM wave form.  The motion/final resting place of the servo motor depends on the duration of the PWM wave form.  To return to some specific position, the PWM wave form needs to return to the appropriate parameters for that position.  to achieve what you want, you need to implement a simple state machine.  when both switches are 'not pressed' the original PWM wave form needs to be continually output.   BTW: the code fails to implement an 'original' PWM wave form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of a standard RC servo is controlled by a pulse whose width varies from 1 to 2ms, repeated about every 20ms. When the servo receives pulses it will move towards the commanded position (eg. 1ms = left 45°, 1.5ms = center, 2ms = right 45°) and stop when it reaches it. While pulses are being received the servo will try to hold its commanded position. If the pulses stop then the servo will turn off, only holding its position mechanically.

Your code appears to produce a series of alternating length pulses with small gaps, eg. for left:- 1ms pulse, 2ms gap, 2ms pulse, 2ms gap (repeated 300 times). The servo requires a single pulse of length 1~2ms, followed by a long gap to make 20ms total, eg:-

```
 output=1;
 timer(20);  // 1ms pulse
 output=0;
 timer(380); // 19ms gap
```

This code segment should be executed whenever the 'Left' button is held down. To move right, make the pulse width 2ms and the gap 18ms.

To return to center, execute the following code continuously whenever *no* buttons are pressed:-

```
 output=1;
 timer(30);  //1.5ms
 output=0;
 timer(370); // 18.5ms
```

Note: This is the correct timing for controlling a servo directly. If you are operating the car via a standard RC transmitter then you may have to encode the signal into PPM (Pulse Position Modulation). This consists of short pulses (~400us) marking the start and end of each servo channel. A 2 channel radio would send 3 pulses per frame.

Answer (score 0):

the following code, for the PIC18, gives the algorithm you need to implement on the 8051.

certain calculations need to be performed to get the proper delay numbers

here are the calculations for the pic18

```
clock frequency = 20mhz = 20,000,000hz

PIC18F452 -> 1 instruct per 4 clock cycles
instruction frequency = (20/4)mhx = 5mhx = 5,000,000hx

1/5,000,000 seconds = (x) instructions = 18.5msec
-> 92,5000 instructions = 18.5msec delay

1/5,000,000 seconds * (x) instructions = 1.5msec
-> 7,500 instructions = 1.5msec delay
```

This algorithm yields continuous movement between 3 positions, but does show how to move the servo

Suggest no switch pressed be 'home' position, switch 1 pressed initiate motion one way,  switch 2 pressed initiate motion the other way.

Suggest initiate motion by telling the servo motor to move to a (as far away as possible end position,  for instance 0degrees and 90 degrees with the home position be 45degrees.

.
This code was lifted from: http://www.pyroelectro.com/tutorials/servo_motor/software.html

```
    #include <p18f452.h>
    #include <delays.h>

    int main(void)
    {

            int count=0;

            TRISB = 0x00;
            PORTB = 0x00;

        while(1)
        {

            for(count=0;count<50;count++)
            {  //far counter-clockwise
                    PORTB = 0x01;
                    Delay1KTCYx(10);
                    PORTB = 0x00;
                    Delay1KTCYx(90);
            }


                //middle
                for(count=0;count<50;count++)
            {
                    PORTB = 0x01;
                    Delay1KTCYx(7);
                    Delay100TCYx(5);
                    PORTB = 0x00;
                    Delay1KTCYx(92);
                    Delay100TCYx(5);
            }


            for(count=0;count<50;count++)
            {  //far counter-clockwise
                    PORTB = 0x01;
                    Delay1KTCYx(5);
                    //Delay100TCYx(5);
                    PORTB = 0x00;
                    Delay1KTCYx(95);
                    //Delay100TCYx(5);
            }
        }
    }
```